# Why isn't @Service creating bean?

Tags: spring, security, service

I have implemented custom UserDetailsService but I can't autowire it because bean is not created. Other services in same package work with same anotations.

```
@Service
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JwtUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new UserPrincipal(userRepository.findByUsername(username));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this a minimal example or could you reduce the code even more to reproduce this issue? Did you check for the right import? (org.springframework.stereotype.Service)

Comment: Is a UserRepository bean available? That might explain why this one can't be created.